# on-screen magnifier

Tags: raspbian-buster, lxde, software-recommendation

What light, simple, on-screen magnifier or "loupe" would you recommend for use with the default Raspbian "Buster" desktop (lxde, PIXEL), please ? Searching "add/remove software" didn't find one within the default repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried any of these, but these all appear to be in Buster: xzoom (an X11 zoom program), kmag, and gnome-mag.

I'd suggest trying xzoom first, since that is most likely the lightweight one of the bunch.

kmag and gnome-mag may pull in a bunch of kde (kmag) or gnome (gnome-mag) stuff, so you might want to try these on a different SD card...just in case.

Comment: @bis: indeed, zoom fits the need perfectly, nothing fancy bur lightweight and its use is intuitive enough. For some reason my searching the "add/remove" applet had not found it  - that search is not very configurable by the way.Thank you !

Comment: fixing typo, "xzoom" not "zoom" was meant in above appreciation.